# Continue timer through View Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I am working on an app that requires timing. The timer activates in one View Controller and it needs to continue until the last View Controller. For example, I have 5 View Controllers and the timer need to start in first View Controller at 15 minutes, then the user starts using the next four View Controllers. When the user reaches the fourth View Controller, then the timer should stop and the user should be shown with an alert how long it took for them to finish.

Comment: Just create the timer as a global variable. Start it anywhere in your code and it should keep on running.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Singleton Class for Timer and initialise the timer when First View is loaded, when you reach your final view check the timer current status.

In order to receive callbacks for time-up you will have to implement local notification, and add each of the view controllers as observers (don't forget to remove them from notification pool when views are destroyed)